# How to connect organization data service of dynamics crm with node.js application

Tags: node.js, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

How do I connect to the organization data service of Dynamics CRM with a node.js application?

I do not have web api in developer resource, so how to get data with organization data service?

[image: dynamic crm version iamge]  ...
[image: developer resource image]

Comment: What version of CRM are you using?

Comment: added image for dynamic version and also developer resource

Comment: you will need to use the SOAP endpoint then due to your CRM version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CRM 2016 or later [Use the Microsoft Dynamics 365 Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593051.aspx)

> The Web API, which is new for Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online &
>   on-premises), provides a development experience that can be used
>   across a wide variety of programming languages, platforms, and
>   devices. The Web API implements the OData (Open Data Protocol),
>   version 4.0, an OASIS standard for building and consuming RESTful APIs
>   over rich data sources.
>
> Because the Web API is built on open standards, we don’t provide
>   assemblies for a specific developer experience. You can compose HTTP
>   requests for specific operations or use third-party libraries to
>   generate classes for whatever language or platform you want.

If you are using CRM 2015 or earlier use the [Organization Service (aka SOAP endpoint)](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/introducing-the-microsoft-dynamics-365-web-services/).

> Available since CRM 2011 the service provided a classic SOAP endpoint
>   and is probably the most commonly used web service. This service
>   provides access to the full range of 365 operations, and messages. For
>   .Net developers the SDK provides a set of assemblies that mean using
>   the service is simple with the complexities of the SOAP endpoint
>   abstracted away. Non-.Net developers have a more challenging
>   environment and they must communicate directly with the SOAP endpoint
>   which is typically a far more complicated affair.

Comment: in my dynamic crm developer resource i dont have web api url please help with this

Comment: @Firasath based on your screenshot you don't have CRM 2016, so this answer does not apply for you

Comment: @jasonscript Is there any way to connect CRM 2015 with organization data service in Node.js with out clientid from azure

Answer (score 0):

Am sharing the github code sample from [this blog](https://alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2015/01/23/authenticating-from-a-node-js-client-to-dynamics-crm-via-ad-fs-and-oauth2/).

This uses OrganizationData service from Node.js script to pull FullName of Contacts (ContactSet).

```
    // Set the headers for the call to CRM
    var headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sess.access_token, //send the oauth access token to authenticate
      'Accept': 'application/json' //tell CRM to send json data back
    }

    //configure the CRM odata request
    var options = {
      host : crm_host,
      port : crm_port,
      path : '/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet?$select=FullName', //hardcoded to select just the contact name
      method : 'GET',
      rejectUnauthorized: false,//to allow for self-signed SSL certificates - use at your own risk!!!
      headers : headers //set in the previous step
    };
    
    var reqGet = https.request(options, function(resGet) {
      //should do something here if we get 'www-authenticate': 'Bearer error' response headers
      //console.log("headers: ", resGet.headers);
      
      resGet.on('data', function(d) {
        //console.info('raw response: ' + d);
        var json = JSON.parse(d);
        var records = json.d.results;
        
        //console.info('results: ' + JSON.stringify(records));
        for (var i in records) {   
          res.write(records[i].FullName + '<br />');
        }
        res.write('</body>');
        res.write('</html>');
        res.end();
      });
    });
    reqGet.end();
    
    //handle errors
    reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
```

Comment: Do we have any  way other than Azure oauth access token to authenticate.How we can get access token

Comment: we are not using azure in same domain.dynamic and azure are in different domain then how can we authenticate azure with dynamics credential.

Comment: can you tell what should be the base url 
path : '/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet?$select=FullName'
before /XRM. . . . . ??

Comment: @AdeelShekhani your organization url.for ex `https://devcrm.crm.dynamics.com`