# Postman (Step by Step ) Authentication and Data Retrieval of Data from Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: node.js, dynamics-crm

Can anybody please guide me to Authenticate and Retrieve Data via Postman for Dynamics CRM 2015 that we have.
New to MS world, so I presume that its not linked to Azure AD, hence I am not sure if there are any OAuth Token that I can generate.

anyway here is some of the info I have

```
User Name       service_user
Password        ****
spn             SVC_USR@ABC.COM.AU
org URL         http://crm.abc.com.au/ABC/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
default realm   ABC.COM.AU
KDC             abc.com.au
```

Ultimate Goal is to write a NodeJS application to talk to Dynamics and Get the Data out of it.

There is thread already on this

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052901/how-to-connect-organization-data-service-of-dynamics-crm-with-node-js-applicatio
```

but talks about bearer token and I don't have bearer token rather user name and password along wih KDC and realm with me

Any guidance/ suggestions

Thanks

Comment: [To get the access token, you use a redirect url after entering username/password](https://alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2015/01/23/authenticating-from-a-node-js-client-to-dynamics-crm-via-ad-fs-and-oauth2/).

Comment: First you need to create an application user in dynamics, and then you can get the token from dynamics. Please follow the instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory